# Issues with ExpCatStat() from SmartEDA package

Tags: r

I'm exploring SmartEDA package which seems to promise a very smooth and fast EDA pipiline.

While the command dedicated to numerical features analysis (ExpNumStat) works properly, ExpCatStat (whose aim is to find out statistics and association related to categorical features) seems to work not so fine (se below).

```
library(SmartEDA)
```

After downloading the orginal dataset, I find myself dealing with the following datatype situation:

```
> str(DataOrigin)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  991346 obs. of  24 variables:
 $ sex             : chr  "Male" "Male" "Male" "Male" ...
 $ age             : num  35 30 40 50 50 50 45 35 55 40 ...
 $ height          : num  170 180 165 175 165 165 150 175 170 175 ...
 $ weight          : num  75 80 75 80 60 55 55 65 75 75 ...
 $ waistline       : num  90 89 91 91 80 75 69 84.2 84 82 ...
 $ sight_left      : num  1 0.9 1.2 1.5 1 1.2 0.5 1.2 1.2 1.5 ...
 $ sight_right     : num  1 1.2 1.5 1.2 1.2 1.5 0.4 1 0.9 1.5 ...
 $ hear_left       : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ hear_right      : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ SBP             : num  120 130 120 145 138 142 101 132 145 132 ...
 $ DBP             : num  80 82 70 87 82 92 58 80 85 105 ...
 $ BLDS            : num  99 106 98 95 101 99 89 94 104 100 ...
 $ tot_chole       : num  193 228 136 201 199 218 196 185 217 195 ...
 $ HDL_chole       : num  48 55 41 76 61 77 66 58 56 60 ...
 $ LDL_chole       : num  126 148 74 104 117 95 115 107 141 118 ...
 $ triglyceride    : num  92 121 104 106 104 232 75 101 100 83 ...
 $ hemoglobin      : num  17.1 15.8 15.8 17.6 13.8 13.8 12.3 14.4 15.1 13.9 ...
 $ urine_protein   : num  1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ serum_creatinine: num  1 0.9 0.9 1.1 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.9 ...
 $ SGOT_AST        : num  21 20 47 29 19 29 19 18 32 21 ...
 $ SGOT_ALT        : num  35 36 32 34 12 40 12 18 23 38 ...
 $ gamma_GTP       : num  40 27 68 18 25 37 12 35 26 16 ...
 $ SMK_stat_type_cd: num  1 3 1 1 1 3 1 3 1 2 ...
 $ DRK_YN          : chr  "Y" "N" "N" "N" ...
```

I try to make SmartEDA anaylize categorical features:

```
ExpCatStat(DataOrigin, Target="DRK_YN")
```

and I get this result:

```
> ExpCatStat(DataOrigin, Target="DRK_YN")
           Variable Target Unique Chi-squared p-value df IV Value Cramers V
1               sex DRK_YN      2  134782.004       0 NA        0      0.37
2         hear_left DRK_YN      2    3373.726       0 NA        0      0.06
3        hear_right DRK_YN      2    3361.427       0 NA        0      0.06
4     urine_protein DRK_YN      6     306.512       0 NA        0      0.02
5  SMK_stat_type_cd DRK_YN      3  131811.460       0 NA        0      0.36
6               age DRK_YN      9   84056.836       0 NA        0      0.29
7            height DRK_YN      7  143629.103       0 NA        0      0.38
8            weight DRK_YN      8   74198.673       0 NA        0      0.27
9         waistline DRK_YN     10   16175.778       0 NA        0      0.13
10       sight_left DRK_YN      8   27379.424       0 NA        0      0.17
11      sight_right DRK_YN      8   26621.453       0 NA        0      0.16
12              SBP DRK_YN     10    2962.157       0 NA        0      0.05
13              DBP DRK_YN     10    9953.357       0 NA        0      0.10
14             BLDS DRK_YN     10    2051.088       0 NA        0      0.05
15        tot_chole DRK_YN     10    1757.942       0 NA        0      0.04
16        HDL_chole DRK_YN     10    2407.852       0 NA        0      0.05
17        LDL_chole DRK_YN     10    2030.896       0 NA        0      0.05
18     triglyceride DRK_YN     10   11570.144       0 NA        0      0.11
19       hemoglobin DRK_YN     10  102321.002       0 NA        0      0.32
20 serum_creatinine DRK_YN      7   38918.921       0 NA        0      0.20
21         SGOT_AST DRK_YN     10    4858.933       0 NA        0      0.07
22         SGOT_ALT DRK_YN     10   10816.237       0 NA        0      0.10
23        gamma_GTP DRK_YN     10   91690.237       0 NA        0      0.30
   Degree of Association Predictive Power
1                 Strong   Not Predictive
2              Very Weak   Not Predictive
3              Very Weak   Not Predictive
4              Very Weak   Not Predictive
5                 Strong   Not Predictive
6               Moderate   Not Predictive
7                 Strong   Not Predictive
8               Moderate   Not Predictive
9                   Weak   Not Predictive
10                  Weak   Not Predictive
11                  Weak   Not Predictive
12             Very Weak   Not Predictive
13                  Weak   Not Predictive
14             Very Weak   Not Predictive
15             Very Weak   Not Predictive
16             Very Weak   Not Predictive
17             Very Weak   Not Predictive
18                  Weak   Not Predictive
19                Strong   Not Predictive
20              Moderate   Not Predictive
21             Very Weak   Not Predictive
22                  Weak   Not Predictive
23                Strong   Not Predictive
Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NA introdotti per coercizione
```

I don't understand some points:

1. what does the warning message about NA coertion mean?
2. why "p-values", "df" and "IV Value" have not been computed? Note that "predictive power is based on IV Value: being the latter always equal to 0, the predictive power is always null.
3. I expected ExpCatStat() would have selected only categorical variables, avoiding numerical ones. It seems all dataset columns have been processed. Why? Isn't it against the logic of the command?

Thanks for your help.

damiano

Comment: Your example doesn't appear to depend on readr, tidyverse or tidymodels, and your library call unnecessarily depends on yet another package. Replace all of that with `library(SmartEDA)` and you make it a lot easier for people to help you. Also, don't link to external data sets if you can help it, especially if they require a sign-up. Try and make your question self-contained, in addition to being a [mcve]

Comment: Is your code minimal and reproducible?